# Extjs store.proxy.extraParams is undefined only in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have an ExtJs store.

```
var fieldsStore = new Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
model : 'FieldsModel',
proxy : {
    type : 'ajax',
    url : 'queryBuilder_getQueryDetails',
    extraParams : {
        queryID : queryID
    },
    reader : {
        type : 'json'
    }
},
listeners : {
    load : function(store, records, successful, operation, eOpts) {
        if (successful) {
            records.forEach(function(rec) {
                // default settings: if datatype is INTEGER - SUM
                if (rec.get('fieldType') == 'INTEGER') {
                    rec.set('fieldSettingKey', 'SUM');
                    rec.set('fieldSettingValue', 'Sum');
                } else {
                    // else select ROWHEADER by default
                    rec.set('fieldSettingKey', 'ROWHEADER');
                    rec.set('fieldSettingValue', 'Row Header');
                }
            });
            store.commitChanges();
        }
    }
}
});
```

Now when I do `fieldsStore.proxy.extraParams.queryID = arrQuery.queryId;`, I am getting an error in Internet Explorer. Not in Chrome or FF but only in IE.

It says `fieldsStore.proxy.extraParams` is null or undefined.

Can anyone help why this is happening only in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an [alternative](http://atechiediary.blogspot.in/2013/06/extjs-storeproxyextraparams-is.html) to this.

```
fieldsStore.proxy.extraParams = {queryID : arrQuery.queryId};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this

fieldsStore.getProxy().setExtraParam( 'queryID', arrQuery.queryId );

Comment: says - `Object doesn't support this property or method`

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
fieldsStore.getProxy().extraParams = arrQuery.queryId;
```

EDIT:

You can erase it, when you do:

**fieldsStore.getProxy().extraParams = {'queryID' : queryID}** this code define your extraParams config automatically.

```
var fieldsStore = new Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
model : 'FieldsModel',
proxy : {
    type : 'ajax',
    url : 'queryBuilder_getQueryDetails',
    //-----------------------
    extraParams : {
        queryID : queryID
    },
    //-----------------------
    reader : {
        type : 'json'
    }
},
...
});
```

Comment: Yeah, you need to do with Json object, like:
{'queryId':arrQuery.queryId} - EDIT: Upps, I'm already read your new commentary. And you don't need to define extraParams : { queryID : queryID}, on Proxy/Store definition, it will be charge with that code.

Comment: pardon me but I couldn't understand you last statement "And you don't need to define extraParams : { queryID : queryID}, on Proxy/Store definition, it will be charge with that code." Can you please elaborate it?